# I am not able to receive file in my jsf controller from dropzone js

Tags: jsf, weblogic, dropzone.js, netui

I am working on Oracle Weblogic server and using JSF with netui.

I need to implement drag and drop for file uploade, but when I drag or drop file it is not available in my jsf controller, formbean is always null.

Comment: What is JPF in your question? Here on SO https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jpf/info is about http://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf/wiki/WikiStart, which is model checking tool, not MVC framework

Comment: @kukeltje It was tagged with jpf and was about jpf, and I've retagged it and replaced jpf word with jsf :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not see a recent edit, but now I do. Great! Thnx